# Dataset for floating objects detection

Tags: deep-learning, datasets

I am looking for a dataset, which I could train a model to detect people/boats/surfboards, etc., from a drone view.

Has anyone seen a dataset that could be useful for this purpose?

I have some photos made by me (like this one below), but I need more data. Of course, the best will be if data will be labeled, but, if someone has seen an unlabeled dataset with videos/photos like that below, please share the link to it.

Sample photos I am looking for:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will be looking for a dataset for maritime SAR (Search and Rescue) purposes in the future, we have created **the first publicly free to use for academic research** dataset of this type:
http://afo-dataset.pl/en/download/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can check this dataset out:
http://www.aiskyeye.com/

> The VisDrone2019 dataset is collected by the AISKYEYE team at Lab of
>   Machine Learning and Data Mining , Tianjin University, China. The
>   benchmark dataset consists of 288 video clips formed by 261,908 frames
>   and 10,209 static images, captured by various drone-mounted cameras,
>   covering a wide range of aspects including location (taken from 14
>   different cities separated by thousands of kilometers in China),
>   environment (urban and country), objects (pedestrian, vehicles,
>   bicycles, etc.), and density (sparse and crowded scenes). Note that,
>   the dataset was collected using various drone platforms (i.e., drones
>   with different models), in different scenarios, and under various
>   weather and lighting conditions. These frames are manually annotated
>   with more than 2.6 million bounding boxes of targets of frequent
>   interests, such as pedestrians, cars, bicycles, and tricycles. Some
>   important attributes including scene visibility, object class and
>   occlusion, are also provided for better data utilization.

It provides many drone view images with bounding boxes. Hope it can help you and have a nice day!